# passing parameters between two nibs: suggestion?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, parameter-passing, nib, class-method

In my main nib (nib1), I have a button that activates another nib (nib2) using the piece of code below.

The way that I currently pass values to nib2 and obtain from nib2 is by creating class methods in nib1.  But one of my goal of this exercise project is that I need to design nib2 such that I will be able to re-use nib2 at another later project.  That implies nib2 should not know anything about nib1's class.  So that when I re-use nib2 at a later time, I do not need to modify its code (to call nib1'class methods.)

I was thinking about creating class methods in nib2's class.  But then how will I be able to call the method before nib2 is active?

Is my approach right?  any comments?

```
NSWindowController *iQWController = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"iQueryWindow"];
[iQWController showWindow:sender];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this example I assume you have class definitions nib1.h/nib1.m/nib1.xib & nib2.h/nib2.m/nib2.xib

You should create properties in nib2 for getting the data into nib 2.

To get data from nib 2 back to nib 1, you should define a delegate protocol, have nib 1 implement it and set it as nib 2's delegate.

nib2.h would look something like:

```
@protocol Nib2Delegate;

@interface Nib2 : UIViewController {
    id <Nib2Delegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <Nib2Delegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol Nib2Delegate 

- (void)myMethod;

@end
```

in Nib1.h you would have:

```
#import "Nib2.h"

@interface Nib1 : UITableViewController <Nib1Delegate> {

}

- (void)myMethod;

@end
```

in Nib1.m

```
Nib2 *nib2 = [[Nib2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Nib2" bundle:nil];
nib2.delegate = self;
```

Then you would implement myMethod in Nib1.m. When you want to call it in Nib2.m it would look like

```
[delegate myMethod];
```

Comment: jopke: your suggestions and code samples are right on.  I changed my original Nib2 from NSView class to NSViewController and (make sure to) set File's Owner as a subclass of Nib2 (NSViewController).  All worked out just as your suggestion.